# How do I change the selected option with dynamically added options?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a php page with some javascript in it.  There are some select elements with static options and some select elements I append options to.  For the static options I can change the selected option using the code below.  But for the dynamically added options I cannot change the selected option.  I have feeling I am not selecting the element correctly since it was not on the DOM originally.

I can dynamically add options to a `select` with this

```
feedback_sub_type.append(new Option(user.value, user.value));
```

However I cannot change the selected option with this

```
$('#feedback_sub_type').val('<?php echo $feedback_sub_type ?>');
```

Comment: It could be many things. It can be a wrong value, it can be a race condition of some kind... with the amount of information provided, there is no way to know. Please post the full relevant part of the code.

Comment: use append to select like $("#yourselectid").append('<?php echo $feedback_sub_type ?>')

Comment: sorry the question is not sufficient to answer,please edit it

Comment: Added a little more info.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work.  Not exactly what I was looking for but it will do.

````
if(user.value != selected_type){
feedback_type.append(new Option(user.value, user.value));
}
else{
feedback_type.append(new Option(user.value, user.value, true, true));}```
````